# slideToggle() Function does not work after scaling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a confusing bug inside my code and do not know how to fix it. I got to main functions, calling scripts depending on the current window size.

For mobile devices I got a `slideToggle()` function, which does work when viewing on a mobile device. But when opening above `600px`, and scaling down the function is fired, but the `slideToggle();` does not work anymore.

Its set to `display: block;` and immediately set to `display: none;` again. My `slideToggle();` is embedded like this:

```
$('.box-header').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('folded').toggleClass('unfolded');
  $(this).next('div').stop().slideToggle();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/75186j96/1/)

When viewing the demo its important to load the page while the window size is above 600px and than scale down to recreate the problem. If it works please try again, as it does work sometimes.

What am I missing? And is there a better approach to kill and call scripts depending on the viewers viewport after resize events?

Comment: what you are missing is, that you are binding the `click` Event more than one time when the window is resized to your breakpoint. try `off('click').on('click')` to unbind all `click` Events before adding a new one.

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code seems fine.

Comment: thanks @chris for your suggestion, this works fine. Please insert it as an answer so I mark it for others to understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put the if in the click event:

```
  $('.box-header').on('click', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('folded unfolded');
      $(this).next('div').stop().slideToggle();
    } else {
      //for other code here for medium+large screens
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5puqn9ts/1/

even use a class to toggle between the mobile and large screen, bind a click event to each

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.mobile', function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('folded').toggleClass('unfolded');
      $(this).next('div').stop().slideToggle();
      console.log('clicked');
    });


  // init scripts for smartphone or desktops
  var initScripts = function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      $('.box-header').addClass('mobile');
    }
    if ($(window).width() >= 600) {
      $('.box-header').removeClass('mobile');
      /add class for medium screen then bind event to ti
    }
  }
  initScripts();

  var id;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    initScripts()
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75186j96/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your function set an event in every call. Try this correct alternative:

```
var smartphoneFunctions = $('.box-header').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('folded').toggleClass('unfolded');
  $(this).next('div').stop().slideToggle();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75186j96/8/

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, you need to adjust your `slideToggle()` target to be `.box-content` rather than the abstract `div` as this will instead apply the toggle on the `.box-header`. Also your class toggling could be bundled.

The resulting code would be the following:

```
$('.box-header').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('folded unfolded');
  $(this).next('.box-content').stop().slideToggle();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

That being said, there are better ways of doing this.
You could tie your classes to the appearance of `.box-content`, like this:

```
.box-content {
    transition: height 300ms;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box.folded .box-content {
    max-height: 0;
}

.box.unfolded .box-content {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: thanks @johnny for the suggestion. While I see some approvments in your code (combining two `toggleClass` statements), sadly it does not solve the problem. You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/75186j96/6/
@Chris has found the correct solution, the multiple calls of `.click` events.

Comment: That fiddle works exactly as you'd expect, according to the question you originally asked. The downvote is unnecessary, though.

Comment: Hey @johnny. I am sorry, but I think that you were not able to recreate the problem in jsfiddle. I have opened the jsfiddle with your answer and tried to show you a visual explanation of the problem: https://vid.me/LDH5
Because of the fact, that your answer does not solve the problem and just changes code I have down voted it (to not be misunderstood by others). Feel free to edit your answer so that I can correct the down vote. Thanks again for your effort and suggestions!

Comment: That's strange, as the same code works well for me: https://vid.me/V2LU
Regardless, you're entitled to vote to whatever you see fit. I am happy you found a solution to your problem.